# How to associate multimedia keys to Foobar2000?

Tags: foobar2000, media-keys

I have a Logitech Internet Pro keyboard, which has the multimedia keys for Media (to launch player) and Play/Pause. How do I associate these keys to launch Foobar2000 and play/pause the song it is playing?

(This is on Windows XP.)

Comment: For anyone who can't see the multimedia key's value show in the preferences, close all your other apps as one of them may have a global hook.  I had configured a Chrome extension for grooveshark to use my MM keys but I couldn't re-associate them with Foobar2000 until I closed Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Multimedia keyboards + foobar2000: A complete guide**](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=50067) detailed everything that I wanted to do with the keyboard.

Comment: It may be a little late. But could you please summarize the content of your link? In case the link goes down

Answer (score 11):

For Play/Pause:

File -> Preferences -> General -> Keyboard Shortcuts

Click *Add New* and setup the binding you want.  Make sure to select **Global Hotkey**.

As for launching from a keystroke, when you edit the properties of a shortcut you can assign a *Shortcut key*.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having trouble with this, check to see if you have the Google Music extension enabled in chrome. Disabling it should fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I might be to late but, they now work by default in the newest version (.9.6.8) if you use Column UI. Oddly enough it doesn't work in the DUI. Also, if you make the media keys global on foobar2000 it won't work on any other applications if foobar is running; just something to keep in mind.